# Search for a line containing characters, hyphen and numbers following hyphen with sed

Tags: search, sed, replace, grep

Let's suppose a file with following content named file.txt is used as a source.

```
12345
ABC-12
XCD-13
BCD-12345
Some text on this line
*+-%&
```

What I am looking for with sed would be to get only ABC-12 line and remove hyphen so the desired output would be `ABC12`

So far I have been able to get numbers only with following command:

```
sed "s/[^0-9]//g" file.txt
```

Output

```
12345
12
13
12345
```

I got the closest with grep with command:
`grep -oP 'ABC-\b\d{2}\b' file.txt`

Output

```
ABC-12
```

How should this be constructed with sed and also hyphen removed from the output?

Note also that numbers after ABC can be considered as changing like a variable so the idea would be to search for "ABC and numbers following it after hyphen" instead of searching for "ABC-12" directly.

Comment: You can use `sed -En 's/^(ABC)-([0-9]+)$/\1\2/p'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> idea would be to search for `ABC` and numbers following it after hyphen

You may use this `sed` for this:

```bash
sed '/^ABC-[0-9][0-9]$/!d; s/-//' file

ABC12
```

Here:

- `/^ABC-[0-9][0-9]$/!d`: Searches input for a line that starts with `ABC` followed by a hyphen followed by 2 digits and end. All non-matching lines are removed due to `!d` as command.
- `s/-//p`: Removes `-` from the match

---

**Update:**

As per comment below if `ABC-` text is not at the start then use:

```bash
sed -nE 's/.*(ABC)-([0-9][0-9]).*/\1\2/p' file
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked great for the file.txt. 
Now when I am thinking more I think my actual use case would be to search `ABC-12` from the middle of line for example


`Line content: ABC-12 this is continued text after searched part`

So think I would need to modify the beginning /^ABC part somehow to search for a line containing ABC instead of line starting with it.

Comment: ok in that case use: `sed -nE 's/.*(ABC)-([0-9][0-9]).*/\1\2/p' file`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```bash
sed -En '/^.*(ABC)-([0-9]+).*/{s//\1\2/p;q}'
```

*Details*:

- `-En` - `E` enables POSIX ERE and `n` suppresses default line output
- `^.*(ABC)-([0-9]+).*` - start of string (here, line), then any text, then `ABC` captured into Group 1, `-`, then one or more digits (captured into Group 2) and then the rest of the line
- `{s//\1\2/p;q}` - if there was a match

  - `s//\1\2/p` - take the same pattern and replace with Group 1 + Group 2 text, and print the result of the substitution
  - `q` - quit (you only need the first match here).

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/y104sK):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='ABC-12
XCD-13
BCD-12345
Some text on this line
*+-%&'
sed -En '/^.*(ABC)-([0-9]+).*/{s//\1\2/p;q}' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
ABC12
```